# Gmail Gadgets will be deprecated?

Tags: google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I saw message in Gmail, that says that The 'Add any gadget by URL' Lab is being deprecated.
I use this feature, and I writing my own Gmail gadget, this feature will be deleted, or not, can I use my gadgets after this, or all will be deleted?

Comment: Best to ask the Gmail people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All gadgets added using that will be deleted. I just lost my google docs gadget!